# How to send a notification with cURL?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, notifications

After a lot of researches, I solved all the errors I got trying to send a notification from my app to the current user. But now, no more errors, but a blank answer.
I use the following code :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications?access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken()."&template=Message&http://google.com"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$page = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);
```

I receive this from Graph : {"data":[],"summary":[]}
And no new notification... Believing Facebook, I must receive {"success": true}.

Any idea ? Thanks.

PS : Sorry if my english is bad, I'm French.

Comment: I noticed that I receive an answer when I get a notification from another thing, app or friend... But I want SEND a notification, NOT read the unread notifs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your cURL options to POST this request, but since you have the Facebook PHP SDK installed, why are you directly calling cURL for this instead of using the API?

```
$result = $facebook->api("/{$user_name_or_id}/notifications/", 'POST', array(
        'template' => 'Message',
       );
```

In order to POST a notification, this must be done from an app that is configured as an "App on Facebook". It also does not appear to work with `me`. You need to explicitly call a username or id.